# "Continue the pattern" and the unprovability of the existence of a single solution

Tags: proof-writing, puzzle

Recently (half an hour ago) an associate of mine asked me to prove that:
Given $x=1\implies y=2, x=2\implies y=4, x=3\implies y=6, x=4 \implies y=a$, prove that there is no single solution to a.

With my current mathematical knowledge, I was stumped. After a few minutes of attempts, I asked him for his solution. He gleefully gave me the "arbitrary function" explanation, and while that was good enough for an intuitive explanation, I wasn't satisfied. I pointed out that that was not a valid proof to him, and a little back and forth ensued.

After a while, I began to think: how *do* I prove that? But of course, I cannot do it on my own. So, I have come to ask ye of MathExchange for a *proof*.

My current insights are:

- It cannot be proven that there are any, one, or many solutions (this requires proof as well).

Comment: After some thinking, I have realized one possible route is to define a solution set for a variable x to a given set of predicates is the set of all x which satisfy all predicates

Comment: Without further "constraints" on the function there is no reason to assert that the obvious pattern: $y=2x$ is the correct one.

Comment: Any choice of $a$ satisfies the axioms of ZF, so take 2 different values for $a$ and then you can't prove any value for $a$ since there is some other that satisfies the conditions.

Comment: If you want a proof then you should first formulate what statement it is you want to prove mathematically, and not as a puzzle. For example, what is a "solution", "$\implies$", what is the domain of the problem etc.

Comment: One explicitely way to show that there are infinite many possibilities how the sequence continues is polynomial interpolation.

Comment: As long as the "x's" are pairwise distinct, we can always find a function having the desired "y's" trivially by simply defining the values. This function can be arbitary pathological , but it always exists. So the "arbitary-function-argument" is actually correct.

Answer (score 2):

Passing a line through 2 given Points $(1,A),(2,B)$ is always Possible. Passing a line through 3 given Points $(1,A),(2,B),(3,C)$ may not always be Possible , unless the Points are co-linear. It is always Possible to put it on a quadratic curve.

Like-wise it is not always Possible to put a quadratic curve on 4 given Points $(1,A),(2,B),(3,C),(4,D)$ , though we can always put a cubic curve.

In other words , given $N$ Points like the earlier Cases , we can always put those Points on a curve of Degree $N-1$ , or higher.

Now , we are given the Points $(1,2),(2,4),(3,6),(4,a)$ , but what-ever we choose for $a$ , we can put the Points on a curve of Degree 3 or higher.

$(1,2),(2,4),(3,6),(4,1)$ : $-(7 x^3)/6 + 7 x^2 - (65 x)/6 + 7$

[image: 1]

$(1,2),(2,4),(3,6),(4,10)$ : $x^3/3 - 2 x^2 + (17 x)/3 - 2$

[image: 10]

$(1,2),(2,4),(3,6),(4,-10)$ : $-3 x^3 + 18 x^2 - 31 x + 18$

[image: -10]

$(1,2),(2,4),(3,6),(4,0)$ : $-(4 x^3)/3 + 8 x^2 - (38 x)/3 + 8$

[image: 0]

$(1,2),(2,4),(3,6),(4,-1)$ : $-(3 x^3)/2 + 9 x^2 - (29 x)/2 + 9$

[image: -1]

**ALL IMAGES AND CALCULATIONS CURTESY OF WOLFRAM ALPHA**

Hence , no matter what $a$ is , we can get a function for that. Hence $a$ is not unique.

It will be unique (or limited in range) if we puts Consistent Constraints like (1) We want a Degree 2 curve. (2) We want a linear curve. Etc.